# SharePoint 2013 search return more unexpected results

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, search-results

With sharepoint 2013, I have a enterprise search site, I use default search box and search result web parts. For example, I was using search criteria 'ALL(123*)' and then received some items back. the items were pdf files. there were some files has no 123 at all, I also checked the library columns since these pdf files were hosted in an document library. I didn't find any columns/metadata has value containing 123. it could be i missing some default managed properties? and is there a practice way that I can see the whole index data and I can know the whole data of the query searching? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Are your PDF files full text searchable? If so, and the document content matches/contains 'ALL(123*)', that would explain the results.

Comment: Yes. but I check the PDF content and I didn't find out any content containing 'All(123*)'

Comment: Per Microsoft, make sure your syntax is correct. https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Not-getting-the-search-results-you-re-looking-for-in-SharePoint-d80687f7-1010-4e6d-add9-584b423289d9      If you want to search for a phrase that contains a parenthesis or double quotation mark, make sure that you enclose the entire phrase (including the parenthesis or double quotation mark) in double quotation marks.

Comment: Thanks James! It seems I need to use double quotation mark. I found out search results has been reduced and all have contain phrase "123". However, I still have a question: if there is a way to allow my to check query log to verify all returning results?

Comment: I would look at this post: https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/searchguys/2013/05/24/query-troubleshooting-post-1/ Since there isn't a unique query log for Search, you will need to navigate the ULS log. Download the ULS Viewer (https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=44020) and run a filter on messages with "Query Processing" in the Category field.